# Could you replicate RubyOnRails AR events in Scala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scala

In Ruby, you can create a class (Model) like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :do_something

  def save
    # do something will get called here magically
    ...
  end


  def do_something
  end
end
```

Now say in scala I want to do the same thing, is this possible?

Basically whenever any method is called in a scala class, `do_something` will get called before it.

Note:  You could add more methods to get called like:

```
before_save :do_something, do_something_else
```

Comment: Are you just talking about DB access or any arbitrary Scala class?

Comment: arbitary scala class, want to learn how you would design such a thing using scala.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [callbacks hooks](https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/wiki/Callbacks) of the [Scala ActiveRecord](https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord) library.

> Scala ActiveRecord provides callback hooks for executing actions
>   before or after the model is saved, deleted, or validated. You can
>   override callback methods and implement logic, if necessary. Nothing
>   is done by default.